# NestJS Mongoose extend Schema and override property of parent

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want my **Class B** to extend a **Class A**. This works as expected, but now I need to override a property of Class A in Class B.

To be specific, I have to make the property from Class A optional for Class B:

```
export class B extends A {
  // This property is available in Class A
  @Prop({ required: false, index: true })
  @ApiProperty()
  propertyToOverride: number;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, trying to make a field that has unique constraint in the parent class, not unique in the child, but it doesn't work. The `Prop` decorator options doesn't get overridden in the child, it still creates a unique index even if setting `unique: false` :(

Comment: I ended up using the Mongoose Discrimnator ([link](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#discriminators) see here). I fixed the unique problem by setting the property in the parent class to optional and then setting the property on its Create-DTO to unique. The validations are not on the db, but at least the api is securing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked about this in NestJS's Discord, and this is the answer I got, from the moderator Scott *(Scott (EN-DE)#0052)*:

> There is no overriding of prop properties. And, the classic inheritance of schema definitions doesn't work either, i.e. with overriding. If you are extending from a schema class, you can only add additional fields to it in your new class. So, it is a reusability tool and not a polymorphism tool. If you need polymorphism, then you need to look at discriminators.

So unfortunately it seems there is no way to do it with inheritance currently :(

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! I ended up using the discriminator, it works fine :)